# SIM800L Mini and Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm

I know there are a lot of threads about this, but i cant find answer for my problem.

I have SIM800L Mini and arduino uno. I want to create basic SMS send application, but problem is with SIM800L. I can connect it with USB-UART and communicate with it via AT terminal. I can set baud rate, send sms etc. But when I connect it with arduino, it doesnt work. Im using LM350 for powering it (4V) and voltage divider with 4k7 and 10k resistor.

Thank you for your help

EDIT:
Here is code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

String Arsp, Grsp;
SoftwareSerial gsm(10, 11); // RX, TX

void setup() {
   // put your setup code here, to run once:

   Serial.begin(9600);
   Serial.println("Testing GSM SIM800L");
   gsm.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
   // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

   if(gsm.available())
   {
      Grsp = gsm.readString();
      Serial.println(Grsp);
   }

   if(Serial.available())
   {
      Arsp = Serial.readString();
      gsm.println(Arsp);
   }
}
```

Here is wiring
[image]

[Codes for arduino](https://exploreembedded.com/wiki/GSM_SIM800L_Sheild_with_Arduino)

[Schematics](https://www.electroschematics.com/13548/introducingsim800l/)

[SIM800L](http://linksprite.com/wiki/images/thumb/8/80/SIM800L_1.jpg/640px-SIM800L_1.jpg)

Comment: Are you have connected ground between arduino and SIM800L?

Comment: thank you for your reply, yes I used one of GND on arduino and connect to the common ground (sim800l, dc-dc, arduino, voltage divider)

Comment: Could you please post your wiring and code what you used? Maybe you have wrong wiring.

Comment: i edited it, so you can check if its something wrong :)

Comment: You're not connected reset pin to arduino. You can try to connect it.
Pin 2 Arduino > Transistor > Reset pin SIM800

Comment: and it needs to be? because i read that reset pin dont need to connect

Comment: so how can i modify code? to use reset pin?

Comment: Ok sorry for missunderstanding. I think you must check that your cable is work perfectly.I doubt if rx pin arduino is not connected properly to tx gsm module. And are you have connected VCC gsm module into GND using resistor?

Comment: no those resistors are from lm350 dc-dc buck, im using 10V/3A and converting it to 4V for VCC sim800l

Comment: and cables are good, i tested them

Comment: Then i'm sorry i have no more clue. I have tested your circuit and mine is working. My only suggestion you rewiring it. Good luck buddy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76408/discussion-between-ian-and-ladiqe).